# Get Maximum Value of a column if one column is not null from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a table which has the following Schema [image: Schema]

I want to get data in the following manner

1. If Parent is null then get the whole row as it is
2. If Parent is not null then get the maximum version and not the row which has the same id as the parent id of the row.

Running the query I should get the following Id's
2, 3, 4, 6.
I would get Id 6 but not Id 1 because 1 is a parent of 6 and 5 and since 6 has the max version then row 6 would get selected.

Comment: I'm too old to read that tiny image text. (Most people here want formatted text, not images.)

Comment: What is the relationship between the first and sixth rows such that you were even comparing them?

Comment: Your image only has a scenario of having a single parent? Could a file have a parent which, in turn, has a parent, and so on?

Comment: @Larnu No that scenario is not possible.. a child file cannot be a parent to other file

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen first row is parent of fixth and sixth row, But since sixth is a child of first row and has a maximum version therefore, first and fifth row will rejected and sixth row would be selected

Comment: Edit, nevermind, i see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created my own sample data, as an image isn't usable. You'll need to adjust this for your own data. This should get you what you're after, however:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,'John.jpg',0,NULL),
                 (2,'Jane.jpg',0,NULL),
                 (3,'George.jpg',0,NULL),
                 (4,'Susan.jpg',0,NULL),
                 (5,'John2.jpg',0,1),
                 (6,'Susan2.jpg',0,4),
                 (7,'John3.jpg',1,1)) AS V (ID, [Filename], [Version], Parent)),
RNs AS(
    SELECT COALESCE(C2.ID,C1.ID) AS ID,
           COALESCE(C2.[Filename],C1.[Filename]) As [Filename],
           COALESCE(C2.[Version],C1.[Version]) AS [Version],
           COALESCE(C2.Parent,C1.Parent) AS [Parent],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C1.ID ORDER BY C2.[Version] DESC) AS RN
    FROM CTE C1
         LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.ID = C2.Parent
    WHERE C1.Parent IS NULL)
SELECT ID, [Filename], [Version]
FROM RNs
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Perfect.. Just perfect and amazing. I spent a whole day designing this query. Thanks alot. You are the best. <3

Answer (score 0):

```
    Create table #tmp (id int, [version] int, parent int)

    insert into #tmp values(1,0,null)
    insert into #tmp values(2,0,null)
    insert into #tmp values(3,0,null)
    insert into #tmp values(4,0,null)
    insert into #tmp values(5,0,1)
    insert into #tmp values(6,1,1)
    --insert into #tmp values(7,2,1)
    --insert into #tmp values(8,2,2)
    --insert into #tmp values(9,3,2)

    --SElect * from #tmp

    SELECT id, version, parent
    FROM(
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY parent ORDER BY version DESC) rn
        FROM #tmp   
    )X
    WHERE ((rn = 1 and parent is not null) or (parent is null))
    AND id not in (SELECT DISTINCT Parent From #tmp where Parent is not null )


    DRop table #tmp
```